# KendoTreeView and AngularJS: icons are not displayed

Tags: css, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

Any idea why the icons are not shown [in this tree](http://plnkr.co/edit/AbcZWcCUPZoxlZ4pF0Rm?p=preview)?

this is the HTML:

```
  <div kendo-tree-view="tree" k-data-source="treeData" k-options="treeOptions"></div>
```

this is the CSS:

```
  #tree .k-sprite {
        background-image: url("http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/web/treeview/coloricons-sprite.png");
      }

   .rootfolder { background-position: 0 0; }
   .folder { background-position: 0 -16px; }
```

and this is the javascript;

```
  $scope.treeData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            data: [
                { text: "Furniture", icon: "folder", items: [
                    { text: "Tables & Chairs", icon: "folder" },
                    { text: "Occasional Furniture", icon: "folder" }
                ] },
                { text: "Decor", icon: "folder", items: [
                    { text: "Bed Linen", icon: "folder" },
                    { text: "Carpets", icon: "folder" }
                ] }
            ]
        });


  $scope.treeOptions = {
        dataSpriteCssClassField: "icon"
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing with the ID of `tree` in your DOM.

Try switching `#tree` to `.k-treeview` and the icons will show:

## [Plunker illustrating this here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YhPaEhET8lUcHpNuPz6a?p=preview)

Comment: thanks. isn't the `tree` in `kendo-tree-view="tree"` a handle that can be used as in $scope.tree ? I thought it was also the DOM id.

Comment: Nope!  Kendo will allow you to set it via `id:` I believe, but otherwise it tries to avoid inserting IDs due to some of the problems introduced in the original Telerik radControls (total opinion there, I don't work for Telerik).

Comment: thanks. By the way, your plunk doesn't work in FF, only Chrome and IE

Comment: I fixed the example and now it works in FF, I changed the location of <style> tag to the body, any idea why it works now? see plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/1wbjBNAZxLTZxTL9kwSV?p=preview